# Transfering data within a MySQL db from one table to another with sql statement

Tags: mysql, insert-select

I have consolidated a joined table with it's related entity as the relationship was one-to-one.

So now the original `ww_staff` table holds the `ww_contacts` details directly.

I wrote the following statement based on what I think is logical from MySQL's perspective
but - its not happy.

Can anyone see a similar solution or a blatent transgression?

```
INSERT INTO 
  ww_staff s 
  (phone, mobile, email, skype) 
VALUES 
(
  SELECT w.phone, w.mobile, w.email, w.skype 
  FROM ww_contacts w
  JOIN ww_staff s
  ON s.staff_ID = w.contacts_ID
);
```

Comment: ha, ha -  "my" sql of course :) - still not btw.

Comment: "Not happy" is not a valid MySQL error message. In this case it's pretty obvious (see Scrum Meister's answer), but please remember that for future posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do an `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement. This will insert new rows and update existing ones:

```
INSERT INTO 
  ww_staff
  (staff_ID, phone, mobile, email, skype) 
SELECT w.contacts_ID, w.phone, w.mobile, w.email, w.skype 
  FROM ww_contacts w
  JOIN ww_staff s
  ON s.staff_ID = w.contacts_ID
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 ww_staff.phone = w.phone, ww_staff.mobile = w.mobile, ww_staff.email = w.email, ww_staff.skype = w.skype
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the VALUES()

```
INSERT INTO ww_staff s (phone, mobile, email, skype) 
SELECT w.phone, w.mobile, w.email, w.skype FROM ww_contacts w
JOIN ww_staff s
ON s.staff_ID = w.contacts_ID;
```

--UPDATE

Since you are selecting from `ww_contacts w JOIN ww_staff` - all the records are there already - and you do not want to insert duplicates, use a update with a join:

```
UPDATE ww_staff s JOIN ww_contacts w ON s.staff_ID = w.contacts_ID
SET s.phone = w.phone, s.mobile = w.mobile, s.email = w.email, s.skype = w.skype;
```

Next time please explain more in your question what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unexpected results! - It seems that I cannot add these fields (phone, mobile, email, skype) to the existing records (staff_ID) - the records are duplicated each time with a new staff_ID. Anyone know why?

Comment: each time you run the query you are duplicating the table. what *are* you trying to do???

Comment: @Jonathan Amend - I can see where I needed to explain my requirements more clearly. Apologies, I won't make the same mistake twice. Both solutions work fine. Thanks.